# How to pass images from local system to ec2 instance for my python program?

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, macos, amazon-ec2

I have a python file in an EC2 instance that converts images to a panorama.
My source images are in my local mac system. Now how do i refer the path to this folder when i execute my program on the instance? Does the image folder HAVE to be in the instance itself to refer to it locally?

Comment: Or should I just push my data to an S3 bucket and read it from there and run my program?

Comment: S3 would be better, in my view, as you are de-coupling compute (instance) from storage.